# How can i give ssh-agent access to a php script, which is executed by www-data (apache)?

Tags: php, apache, ssh

**Is there a way, to give www-data (apache) access on ssh-agent?** I have a simple php (cli) script, which simply connects a remote ssh server and run a simple command. On CLI I first start ssh-agent and load key which I protected by a passphrase.

Load agent a key:

```
# eval $(ssh-agent -s)
# ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

PHP CLI script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$connection = ssh2_connect('host', 22);

if (ssh2_auth_agent($connection, 'username')) {
  echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
} else {
  die('Authentication Failed...');
}

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'sh int status');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);

echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

On CLI this works fine, but when I run the above snippet under apache, I can't authenticate on remote ssh host. I think the issue is, that the php/apache has no access on the ssh-agent.

My question: is there a way to start ssh-agent and load key for apache, so that apache has access on it?

Comment: When you do it from CLI, are you the same user has the one that runs Apache?  Apache will try to load the key for the user running it, not your user.

Comment: **No**, on cli i'm root and apache runs the snippet under user www-data. And www-data has no access to ssh-agent. The error log show: `ssh2_auth_agent(): Failure connecting to ssh-agent`. And this is my issue: How can i configure apache, to connect ssh-agent?